# How to get params value on airflow?

Tags: python, airflow

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.models.param import Param
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd

default_args = {
    "owner": "bedirhan",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "start_date": datetime(2023, 12, 22),
    "email_on_failure": False,
    "email_on_retry": False,
    "retries": 0,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
}


def read_csv(**kwargs):
    file_path = kwargs.get("file_path")
    target_id = kwargs.get("target_id", 0)
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path)

    if target_id != 0:
        filtered_df = df[df["id"] == target_id]
        print(f"Rows with id {target_id}:")
        print(filtered_df)
    if target_id == 0:
        print("CSV file content:")
        print(df)


with DAG(
    default_args=default_args,
    dag_id="csv_read_file",
    tags=["test"],
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    params={
        "target_id": Param(
            0,
            type="integer",
            minimum=0,
        ),
    },
) as dag:
    csv_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id="read_csv",
        python_callable=read_csv,
        op_kwargs={
            "file_path": "dags/test.csv",
            "target_id": dag.params["target_id"],
        },
    )
```

I have a code like this. And I have a csv file that include id, firstname and lastname.
Although I give an id value on airflow UI like 105. It gives me all datas. However I want all datas only I give 0 as params["target_id"]. Otherwise I just want to see related data on output.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: program may get it as text so you have to compare with string `"0"`. Or you may have to convert to `int()`

Comment: instead of `if target_id == 0:` you can use `else:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [docs on params](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/params.html) to learn how to pass them to operators.

```
with DAG(
    default_args=default_args,
    dag_id="csv_read_file",
    tags=["test"],
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    render_template_as_native_obj=True,
    params={"target_id": Param(0, type="integer", minimum=0)}
) as dag:
    csv_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id="read_csv",
        python_callable=read_csv,
        op_kwargs={
            "file_path": "dags/test.csv",
            "target_id": "{{ params.target_id }}"
        }
    )
```

Note the DAG-level `render_template_as_native_obj` that makes target_id receive the param as integer rather than a string.